# Write array to a CSV in nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, csv, fs

I'm trying to write an array to a CSV using the `fs` module in node.  Every time do so, it creates new columns because of the commas in the array. How can I  go about doing this without creating new columns - the array should be contained within the column. My code below.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('data.csv');
writeStream.write(`brands \n`);
writeStream.write(`${brands}\n`);
```

The array is just a list of strings: `var brands = ["h2O, "glycerin", "cetyl", "ethylhexanoate"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[edit after OP's clarification]

You can use `Array.join()` to join single elements wrapping them in double-quotes and separating them with commas:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const brands = ["h2O", "glycerin", "cetyl", "ethylhexanoate"]

const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('data.csv');


writeStream.write(`brands \n`);

writeStream.write('[ "' + brands.join('","') + '" ]\n');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to put all the items in an array format in the same row. So for example: the brands row would have "["h2O, "glycerin", "cetyl", "ethylhexanoate"]"

Comment: @Viper You need the square brackets and double-quotes too?

Comment: Yes, i do need this

Comment: @Viper Edited my answer according to your clarification. Does it help?